# How use hash except with array values ? Or how create hash line?

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

Trying to use Hash except with many values from a code

H1 = Hash[:state =>1, code => 2]

H2 = Hash[:state =>10, code => 20]

This work:

```
H1.except(:state, :code)
```

the Hash -> H1 will not contain the values. OK

But bellow is not works

```
H1.expect(H2.keys)
```

the Hash -> H1 will contain the values. NOT

The problem is because the ruby put the order.keys with BRACKET. I tried to generate from array but also not work

Answer (score 10, accepted):

What you're doing amounts to calling `H1.except([:state, :code])`.

If the `H1.except(:state, :code)` works, just unsplat the array:

```
H1.except(*H2.keys)
```

Comment: @ArupRakshit: I don't have the beginning of the clue... but he's definitely missing an unsplat operator. :-)

Comment: I see it is Rails method... :) Thanks for the link!

Answer (score 2):

You can do this in a one-liner using a lambda:

```
h1 = {:state => 1, :code => 2, :foo => 3, :bar => 4}
h2 = {:state =>10, :code => 20}
h1.select {|k,v| !h2.keys.include?(k)}
```

yields

```
{:foo=>3, :bar=>4}
```

Answer (score 1):

A workaround you can do is :

```
H2.keys.each do |key|
  H1.except(key)
end
```